# Cant change the code in CSS

Tags: css

I cannot seem to change my .CSS (the file name is loginmodule.css)

I only wanted to change the font color to black.

I have edited this in Microsoft FrontPage,notepad++, notepad and it has already change but when I look it in the browser(Firefox beta, latest patch). It didn't change at all. I know I had not made a duplicate file and I am sure it is the same file I edited and opened from a browser(Firefox beta, latest patch). Is it because of the browser or something else?

```
body {
    color: #666666;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #f8f7e5 url('images/abstract-bg.jpg') no-repeat center top;; font-style:normal; font-variant:normal; font-weight:normal; font-size:11px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:0px

}
.textfield {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333333;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
h1 {
    color: blue;
    margin: 0px 0px 5px;
    padding: 0px 0px 3px;
    font: bold 18px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #E6E8ED;
}

h2 {
    font: bold 14px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px 0px 5px;
    padding: 0px 0px 3px;
    color: #99CCFF;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #E6E8ED;

}

a {
    color: #2D3954;
    font-size: 11px;
}
a:hover {
    color: #99CC00;
}
.err {
    color: #FF9900;
}
th {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}

#content {
    width: 860px;
    margin: 238px auto 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Which font-color are you trying to change to black? You can always try `font-color : black!important` to see if it's a specificity issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be certain the file hasn't been cached by the browser, just append a query string to the CSS file declaration.

So inside your page/template, change the `<link />` attribute like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/loginmodule.css?v=2" />
```

Alternatively, hold down CTRL and press F5 inside Firefox to do a **hard** refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers typically cache the CSS.  Try closing all of your browser windows then viewing the file.

Answer (score 0):

Things like that usually occur from browsers. I usually delete all history and `clear cache`and it works fine. But make sure you have saved and uploaded the css to the correct directory. You can also try to view it in a browser that you don't use very often.

good luck.